# Is there a way to find all overrides of a PsiMethod?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am developing a plugin for Intellij IDEA 2018.2+.

I need to find all overrides for a given method.
I tried searching among various `PsiUtil`classes to find overrides of:

- `PsiMethod`
- `PsiClass`- to later manually scan methods of overriding class to find whether there are some overriding methods

and yet no luck.

So overall - what is the simpliest way to find all overrides of a given `PsiMethod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found an excerpt from [PSI Cookbook](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/psi_cookbook.html):

> How do I find the methods overriding a specific method?
>
> `OverridingMethodsSearch.search()`

And for class:

> How do I find all inheritors of a class?
>
> `ClassInheritorsSearch.search()`